# Limit users access

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent unpaid user from log in in my website and this codes my login page php codes.

```
enter <?php session_start(); 
include_once('includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$pass=md5($_POST['password']);
$useremail=$_POST['uemail'];

$ret= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,fname FROM users WHERE email='$useremail' and 
password='$pass'");


$num=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
if($num>0)
{

$_SESSION['id']=$num['id'];
$_SESSION['name']=$num['fname'];

header("location:welcome.php");

}
else
{
echo "<script>alert('Invalid username or password');</script>";
}
}
?>
```

and mysql table:
id  username email password paid_unpaid

in this database I want prevent unpaid user from access to website

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use it again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords using the obsolete, insecure md5 algorithm - that is another security risk. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords).

Comment: I guess you copied this code off some dodgy, out-of-date tutorial and don't really understand it. And anyway it's unclear where you're having a problem...this is just the login bit. If you want to stop people accessing a specific page you have to write some code on that page to check if the Session values created by a successful login process are present or not. Any _worthwhile_ login tutorial would show you that already.

Answer (score 0):

Just create Login table `paid-status enum (0,1)` if paid `1` else default `0`
then check

```
($con,"SELECT id,fname,paid-status FROM users WHERE email='$useremail' and 
password='$pass' and paid-status='1'");
```

in paid screen update paid-status `0` to `1` in particular login user

Comment: Thanks, your code is working,but but can not hide specified page from access